# How to bring an edit and a button to the center of the parent view

Tags: android, xml

The following is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_search"
            android:onClick="searchUsingTag" />   

</LinearLayout>     

</RelativeLayout>
```

But this is not exactly what I want. I want something like google search. There is a long edit box and then a small button.

[image]

Comment: Put each element into diferent linear layouts inside your `linearlayout`. Then, set the width of your text element to `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width of the lineary layout to fill parent and experiment with the weights till you get desired effect.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="searchUsingTag"
        android:text="@string/button_search" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: they are on the top of the view.

Comment: i have edited the code. I thought you included linear layout inside relative layout. The edited code should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `layout_weight` attribute in the **LinearLayout**, you'll have to set this layout to match his parent :

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
              ...
```

then you can play with weight as you tried, to set different sizes to its children.
also : you have to set a weight on each of the children, in your example, the textView with push the button outside the parent since the button doesn't have a weight set.

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment, you need to set this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="5" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="searchUsingTag"
            android:text="@string/button_search" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each element into diferent layouts. Also remember to add all **IDS** (you forgot to add button id) and set your `EditText` width to `fill_parent` and then you get an `EditText` like 'Google' search field or set your own size.

**SUGGEST**

Personally, I prefer to use `LinearLayout` as main layout instead to use `RelativeLayout`. This is **ONLY** a suggestion. If you prefer it relative, never mind.